# How to get instance of DbContext in ASP.NET Core 2.0 where I want?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How to get instance of DbContext in ASP.NET Core 2.0 where I want?
To connect DataBase I used services

```
string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<MobileContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext):

Excerpt:

> EF Core supports using DbContext with a dependency injection container. Your DbContext type can be added to the service container by using the AddDbContext method.
>
> AddDbContext will make both your DbContext type, TContext, and the corresponding DbContextOptions available for injection from the service container.
>
> Application code (in ASP.NET Core):

```
public class MyController
{
  private readonly BloggingContext _context;

  public MyController(BloggingContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  ...
}
```

> Application code (using ServiceProvider directly, less common):

```
using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>())
{
  // do stuff
}

var options = serviceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptions<BloggingContext>>();
```

Comment: You should create a scope in your service-locator example code, since the context will be scoped and can't be retrieved directly from the the injected service provider.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Your application can now pass the DbContextOptions when instantiating a context, as follows:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

using (var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
  // do stuff
}
```